# Accessing EJB 2 in wildfly gives error: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, ejb-2.x

I am trying to migrate an ear application from JBoss 4.2 to wildfly 9. I need to deploy an EJB 2 stateless session bean for this. After doing the JNDI lookup, when I try to invoke a business method it fails with the following error:

```
01:47:46,451 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-6) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component TestService for method public abstract java.lang.String in.hinote.ejb.TestServiceLocal.foo(java.lang.String): java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.EjbExceptionTransformingInterceptorFactories$2.processInvocation(EjbExceptionTransformingInterceptorFactories.java:103)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at in.hinote.ejb.TestServiceLocal$$$view8.foo(Unknown Source)
    at in.hinote.actions.TestAction.execute(TestAction.java:53)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And in the action I have the following code:

```
   final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    final String appName = "WildEar";
    final String moduleName = "WildEarEJB";
    final String distinctName = "";
    final String beanName = "TestService";
    final String viewClassName = TestServiceLocal.class.getName();

    TestServiceLocal local = (TestServiceLocal) context.lookup("java:global/" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
    local.foo("foo");
```

Here is the source code for my EJB:

```
/**
 *
 * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
 * A generated session bean
 * <!-- end-user-doc -->
 * *
 * <!-- begin-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @ejb.bean name="TestService" 
 *           description="An EJB named TestService"
 *           display-name="TestService"
 *           jndi-name="TestService"
 *           type="Stateless" 
 *           transaction-type="Bean"
 * 
 * <!-- end-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @generated
 */

public abstract class TestServiceBean implements javax.ejb.SessionBean {

/** 
 * <!-- begin-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * <!-- end-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @generated
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/** 
 *
 * <!-- begin-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @ejb.create-method view-type="remote"
 * <!-- end-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @generated
 *
 * //TODO: Must provide implementation for bean create stub
 */
public void ejbCreate() {
}

/** 
 *
 * <!-- begin-xdoclet-definition --> 
 * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
 * <!-- end-xdoclet-definition -->
 * @ejb.transaction type = "Never" 
 *
 */
public String foo(String param) {
    System.out.println(param);
    return null;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.ejb.SessionBean#ejbActivate()
 */
@Override
public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.ejb.SessionBean#ejbPassivate()
 */
@Override
public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.ejb.SessionBean#ejbRemove()
 */
@Override
public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.ejb.SessionBean#setSessionContext(javax.ejb.SessionContext)
 */
@Override
public void setSessionContext(SessionContext arg0) throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * 
 */
public TestServiceBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

JNDI lookup seems to be working. It fails only when I call the business method: testService.foo(). Am I missing anything? Please help.

Could this be a security related issue? I've configured a security realm and assigned a particular role for this ejb method. But even then I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to so a remote lookup, right?

Comment: No, Is there a mistake? I am trying to access local interface only. Because wildfly server runs in local system only.

Comment: Because you have the client naming package prefix Set for your context.

Comment: oh. what should it be?

Comment: I think that this part is only needed for remote lookup using the client API. Try omitting it

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help either. I'm getting the same error. JNDI lookup seems to be returning the correct object. It fails only when I try to invoke a method.

Comment: Ok, please post the EJB class. I'm not so familiar with EJB2 but the Stack trace says something about abstract...

Comment: I've edited the post to include my EJB. Please check

Comment: Can you try to remove the abstract modifier? Maybe this is the reason that the Container cannot instanciate the bean

Comment: Many thanks. That was the problem indeed. I autogenerated this bean using eclipse, didn't notice the abstract modifier. Many thanks again

Comment: Hey, R u using seam?, if yes please post the seam version also which version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: @SreenathReddy Sorry. No I'm not using seam. neither hibernate.

Comment: Fine, I also faced similar issue, it was resolved after upgrading my hibernate to 4.0

Comment: Normal EJB2 practice was to look up a [javax.ejb.EJBLocalHome](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EJBLocalHome.html) in JNDI and use that to create the `TestServiceLocal`. I think you may still need to do this.

Comment: Yes initially that's what I was doing. But since it was not working, I tried this after looking at the wildfly jndi tree. But yes, as you said LocalHome should also work with this, but didn't try it so far.